# Set of odd integers is not definable in $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ by an existential formula

Tags: model-theory

I would like some comments on how I approach this problem. The part right before this problem in my homework asks for an existential formula that defines the set of even integers. Please let me know if my thoughts are not correct or could be better.

*Edit: the language contains just one binary function symbol.*

Let $\phi(v_1)$ be the formula $\exists v_2(v_2+v_2=v_1).$ Then $\phi(v_1)$ defines the set of all even integers since only even integers are divisible by two. *(not sure if I can use divisibility here because language has no divide symbol.)* The negation of the formula thus defines the set of all odd integers. Since $\lnot \exists v_2(v_2+v_2=v_1) $ is equivalent to $\forall v_2 \lnot (v_2+v_2 = v_1)$, the set of odd integers is not definable by an existential formula.

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: Why not $\exists v_2(v_2+v_2+1=v_1)$?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 One would expect $1$ to not be part of the language.

Comment: the language didn't have a constant symbol for 1. I should have made that clearer!

Comment: @jh4: It's a legitimate notation to use $(\Bbb Z,+)$ to mean that only $+$ is available in the language.

Comment: Does there exist an existential formula that is false for $0$? Because I would like to speculate that every set of this type is a union of sets of the type $a\mathbb Z$.

Comment: ... or the empty set. Because of $(\exists x)(x\neq x)$ stuff.

Comment: @Myself: $\exists v_1(x+v_1\neq v_1)$ is false for $0$.

Comment: Ok my last comment should be read as a speculation that each existential formula can be examined over $\Bbb Z$ by observing that it falls apart into a union of solution sets of systems of linear equations (this is just DNF). Such a system could have no solutions, but otherwise $0$ will definitely be one of those solutions. One could aim for a canonical form by using gaussian reduction over $\Bbb Q$ and then taking the intersection with $\Bbb Z$ if desired. (But this speculation didn't take into account that there may be negations of equations.)

Comment: To answer one of the OP's specific questions: your second paragraph is not a valid proof. You have shown that the set of odd integers is definable by a universal formula - but that is not the same as not being definable by an existential formula.

Comment: I think this would work: if $P(1,v_1,v_2,...,v_k)$ is true, for $P$ involving only addition and with no quantifiers, then $P(2,2v_1,2v_2,...,2v_k)$ is true, so if existential formula in our language holds for $1$ for some witnesses $v_1,...,v_k$, then it also holds for $2$ with witnesses $2v_1,...,2v_k$, thus no formula can hold for odd numbers only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll show the following fact: if $P(x_1,x_2,...,x_k)$ is quantifier free in the language of $(\Bbb Z,+)$, then for all $v_1,...,v_k$ we have $P(v_1,...,v_k)\Leftrightarrow P(2v_1,...,2v_k)$. Indeed, by induction on construction of well-founded formulas: formula $t_1+...+t_i=t_{i+1}+...+t_j$ is true iff $2t_1+...+2t_i=2t_{i+1}+...+2t_j$ is, because multiplying by 2 preserves truth of such formula. Further, if $Q(t_1,...,t_i)\Leftrightarrow Q(2t_1,...,2t_i)$ then $\neg Q(t_1,...,t_i)\Leftrightarrow \neg Q(2t_1,...,2t_i)$, and if also $R(t_{i+1},...,t_j)\Leftrightarrow R(2t_{i+1},...,2t_j)$, then $Q(t_1,...,t_i)\lor r(t_{i+1},...,t_j)\Leftrightarrow Q(2t_1,...,2t_i)\lor R(2t_{i+1},...,2t_j)$. All other well-founded formulas can be reached like that.

Now suppose that existential formula $\exists v_1,...,v_k:P(x,v_1,...,v_k)$ defines set of odd numbers. Then we can find $t_1,...,t_i$ so that $P(1,t_1,...,t_i)$. But, by above, then we have $P(2,2t_1,...,2t_i)$, so $\exists v_1,...,v_k:P(2,v_1,...,v_k)$, meaning that $2$ is odd number. Contradiction.

Comment: thank you for the answer, this is quite enlightening. I'm not sure what well-founded formulas mean, but I do understand the second paragraph.

Comment: I'm just going through my notes and I found the statement "Embedding preserves truth values of existential formulas". I'm not sure if well-founded formulas mean the same, but I used your approach and argued that since $f(n)=2n$ is an embedding from $\mathbb{Z} to \mathbb{Z}$, then an existential formula that defines 1 would say also that 2 is odd, a contradiction. Is that right?

Comment: @jh4 Indeed, this is correct. (This is the standard argument.)

Answer (score 0):

($\#$) Recall that embeddings preserve the truth of existential formulas.

Suppose for a contradiction that $\varphi(x)\in L$ defines the set of odd integers. The map $f:x\mapsto 2x$ is an embedding of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ into itself. By ($\#$) above $\mathbb{Z}\models\phi(n)$ implies $\mathbb{Z}\models\phi(fn)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Contradiction.